# Syntax error when trying to render form field in Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-babel, flask-babel

I am trying to get the placeholder on my form to be translated with Flask-Babel's `_()` function.

```
{{ render_field(form.search, placeholder="{{ _('Buscar') }}" }}
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/home/john/Scripts/Python/games/templates/index.html", line 45, in template
    {{ render_field(form.search, placeholder="{{ _('Buscar') }}" }}
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}', expected ')'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing `)` in your source code

```
{{ render_field(form.search, placeholder="{{ _('Buscar') }}" }}
#                                                           ^
{{ render_field(form.search, placeholder="{{ _('Buscar') }}") }}
#                                                           ^
```

simple :)